# Fixing pkg-config using Apple silicon and homebrew

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1, pkg-config

I am working with C++ on an M1 Mac, and I used Time Machine to get my old laptop's data on the new one once I got it. The old laptop was not an Apple silicon MacBook. The problem is that I think this screwed up my homebrew installation, since it changed the default location from `/usr/local/Cellar/` to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/` and so now I have two homebrew versions since I installed it again on my new laptop after I got it (since nothing was working with homebrew at first and thought it didn't carry over using Time Machine, oops)

I didn't use homebrew much until recently so I didn't notice, but it has made compiling C++ programs with external libraries very difficult since everything I need is on my new homebrew installation in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/` **except** `pkg-config`, which when I call it in a bash script or on the command line points to my old homebrew installation.

For example, I have `pugixml` in my new installation of homebrew and when I enter `pkg-config --libs --cflags pugixml`

```
Package pugixml was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pugixml.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pugixml' found
```

`pkg-config` finds the libraries in the older homebrew installation just fine

My only alternative is to manually inspect the `.pc` files in the new homebrew installation and enter the flags in my Makefile. I would prefer not to do this. What's the best way to make sure that `pkg-config` works correctly? If someone knows how to get the new installation of `pkg-config` to be used at the command line that would solve all my problems I have right now

edit: I forgot to mention this - when I use the `which` command and ask `which pkg-config` it outputs `/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config`. This is sort of confusing since this is the new location

Answer (score 0):

Remove the old (Intel) installation with the [official uninstall script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh).

You have to make it executable with:

```
chmod +x uninstall.sh
```

And run it with

```
./uninstall.sh --path=/usr/local
```

Then reinstall everything you need on the new M1 version under `/opt/homebrew`.